# setup.py script doesn't identify module

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have the following tree:

```
myPackage
|_myPackage
|    |_mainScript.py
|    |_f1.py
|    |_f2.py
|    |_Rscript.R
|    |_ __init__.py
|_setup.py
|_MANIFEST.in
|_README.md
```

My aim is to create a setup.py file to install myPackage and to make it callable directly using the mypackage command from terminal.

the setup block from the setup.py code looks like this:

```
setup(
name=NAME,
version="1.0.0",
long_description=ldesc,
long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
author=AUTHOR,
author_email=EMAIL,
python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
url=URL,
packages=["myPackage"],
install_requires=REQUIRED,
package_data={"": ["*.R"]},
include_package_data=True,
entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
        "mypackage=myPackage:main",
        ],
    },
#include_package_data=True,
classifiers=[
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Lesser Public License v3 or Later",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
    "Programming Language :: R",
    "Programming Language :: R :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: R :: 3.6",
    "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
    "Operating System :: OS Independant",
    ],
)
```

Installation works, but I get the errorModuelNotFoundError: No module nmed "myPackage".
I also tried to use:

- package_dir = {"": "myPackage"},
- packages = find_packages()
- scripts=["myPackage/mainScript.py.py"]

However, it returns the same error.
I would appreciate some help on this. I'm using Python3.6.0 and Ubuntu.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```py
"console_scripts": ["mypackage=myPackage.mainScript:main"],
```

assuming that's where `def main():` lives?

Comment: I tried it but it returns module myPackage.mainScript has no attribute main and this is what I don't get since I have the if __name__ = __main__: line

Comment: @JKeller for this answer to work properly, a **function** called `main` is required in the file `myPackage/mainScript.py`.